# simple expandable vertical menu, java script problem

Tags: customization, menus, javascript

I am trying to create a simple expandable menu in wordpress.
Bellow you can see the javascript I am using (copy and mix from internet).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#access li').has('ul').addClass('has_submenu');
        $('#access ul li.has_submenu a').click(function() {
            $("#access ul ul").toggleClass("showHide");
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

The **first part is ok**, script adds has_submenu class to my menu.

**Second part** should toggle showHide class.
My problem is that when I click the showHide class appears but dissapears right after(page reloads).

Thanx for help :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#access li').has('ul').addClass('has_submenu');
        $('#access ul li.has_submenu > a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#access ul ul").toggleClass("showHide");
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

See [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in the jQuery API.

Comment: hi mike, thank you .. works partially 
I will try to put it online somewhere ... the menu that has submenus cannot be clicked

Comment: Bellow you can see the link to my problem  :)

http://matusdesign.com/wp/?page_id=90
Page with submenu + all subpages are not clickable.
You think you can help?

thanx

Comment: Yes, in your "click" function it selected all "a" children within your "li.has_submenu", thus also the links of the submenu items themselves. To avoid that you can use the child selector ">". I updated the code.

Comment: I am trying to do a menu as you can see on the page bellow.

http://www.vildlaks.dk/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=19&Itemid=30

Still not working the way I would like to.
http://matusdesign.com/wp/?page_id=233

Comment: So the child selector '>' goes only one level down?

-----------------------
one more question ...
$('#access li').has('ul').addClass('has_submenu');
this adds class 'has_submenu' to #access li

what if I would want to addClass to  '#access' or '#access li ul li a' 
or to some other element ..

Comment: Sorry but I guess that would be another quesiton, I think your initial problem is resolved. Now it seems you want to keep the submenu opened once you are on a submenu page. For that you have to use the `current_page_ancestor` class of the `li` that contains your submenu. Try with `.current_page_ancestor .sub-menu{display:block;}`

Comment: all works, only the page with submenu is not clickable

Comment: It's not clickable because we prevented the linking action (loading new page) to replace it with the submenu opening action (that's what you wanted to do in your initial question!). If you want to be able to put a link on it, then remove the `event.preventDefault();`